# Vue.js 3 v-if ternary function, how to pass object as a conditional

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, ternary

```
<div :class="cellProps.rowData.BrandColor ? 'bluText' : 'redText'">
    <p v-if="cellProps.rowData.BrandColor ? message='cellProps.rowData.BrandColor' : message='NO VALUE PRESENT' ">Brand Color#: {{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

I am bringing in data off a Data Table and with a v-if I am checking to see if `cellProps.rowData.BrandColor` has a value, if it does I want to use that value as the message, if not, use "NO VALUE PRESENT".

The class works fine, but passing in the value as a message is not working correctly. I am getting the feeling that I am not passing it correctly to message. What would be the proper way to pass the value `cellProps.rowData.BrandColor` to message ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<div :class="cellProps.rowData.BrandColor ? 'bluText' : 'redText'">
    <p v-if="cellProps.rowData.BrandColor ? 
     message='cellProps.rowData.BrandColor' : message='NO VALUE PRESENT' 
    ">Brand Color#: {{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

To set `message='cellProps.rowData.BrandColor'` , I learned to just drop the single quotes like this:

```
 message= cellProps.rowData.BrandColor
```

Final version:

```
<div :class="cellProps.rowData.BrandColor ? 'bluText' : 'redText'">
    <p v-if="cellProps.rowData.BrandColor ? 
     message= cellProps.rowData.BrandColor : message='NO VALUE PRESENT' 
    ">Brand Color#: {{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of `v-if`/`v-else`:

```
<div :class="cellProps.rowData.BrandColor ? 'bluText' : 'redText'">
    <p v-if="cellProps.rowData.BrandColor">Brand Color#: {{ cellProps.rowData.BrandColor}}</p>
    <p v-else>Brand Color#: NO VALUE PRESENT</p>
</div>
```

Which can be shortened with the use of `span` inside `p`:

```
<div :class="cellProps.rowData.BrandColor ? 'bluText' : 'redText'">
    <p>
        Brand Color#: 
        <span v-if="cellProps.rowData.BrandColor">{{ cellProps.rowData.BrandColor }}</span>
        <span v-else>NO VALUE PRESENT</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this way as well:

```
<p v-if="cellProps.rowData.BrandColor"> .... </p> 
<p v-if="!cellProps.rowData.BrandColor"> NO VALUE PRESENT</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `v-if` with ternary operator to *set a data property* is wrong.
You can use @Anurag Srivastava solution, or You can use a `computed property`. Here is the code:

```html
<div :class="cellProps.rowData.BrandColor ? 'bluText' : 'redText'">
    <p v-if="cellProps.rowData.BrandColor ? 
     message='cellProps.rowData.BrandColor' : message='NO VALUE PRESENT' 
    ">Brand Color#: {{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

Using `options api`:

```js
export default() {
  // ...
  computed: {
    message() {
      return this.cellProps.rowData.BrandColor ?? 'NO VALUE PRESENT'
    }
  },
  // ...
```

Using `composition api` with script setup:

```js
import { computed } from 'vue'
// ...
const message = computed(() => props.cellProps.rowData.BrandColor ?? 'NO VALUE PRESENT')
// ...
```